# jQuery: how to do something only if element exist?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and i think this question was answered many times. But i can't suggest how to find it. While writing jQuery code, i often write constructions where selector is repeated:

```
if( $( ".someclass .someclass #someid" ).filter( ":visible" ) )
{
  $( ".someclass .someclass #someid" ).filter( ":visible" ).click();
  // This must be executed only if element was found.
  return;
}
// This must be executed only if first element not found
if( $( ".someotherclass #someotherid" ).filter( ":hidden" ) )
{
  $( ".someotherclass #someotherid" ).filter( ":hidden" ).show();
  return;
}
```

As you can see, selector text is repeated. Is it any way to re-use result of last matched selector inside "if()"? For example, something like:

```
if( $( ".someclass .someclass #someid" ).filter( ":visible" ) )
{
  $( ":last-result" ).click();
  return;
}
if( $( ".someotherclass #someotherid" ).filter( ":hidden" ) )
{
  $( ":last-result" ).show();
  return;
}
```

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't test, this won't make any error if there is no matching element :

```
$( ".someclass .someclass #someid:visible").click();
```

This being said, as you can only have one element with a given id, you probably should use

```
$("#someid:visible").click();
```

Now, supposing you really want to do a test, then you may use

```
$("#someid:visible").each(function(){
     var $element = $(this);

     // use $element

});
```

Another basic solution is to cache your element before the test :

```
 var $element = $("#someid");
 if ($element.is(":visible")) {
     // use $element
 }
```

Comment: This was my first fought :). Unfortunately, in many cases i need to click/show/hide **and** do something else. For example, in my code sample - return from method. Or write something to log. Or whatever.

Comment: It's not clear what you want but you can use `this` in most cases if you use each.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, i can't understand. If i add it to next line after "click" - it will execute if element is visible **and** if it's not visible. And it's common to do logic like "if something is visible - hide and return. Than check if something else if not visible, if so - show and return. Finally, check some element has text. If so, clear and return."

Comment: Yes, something like temporary variable. Does jQuery provides some shortcut to it like "last-match"?

Comment: No, that wouldn't really make sense. If you need to use a value more than once, declare a variable. See the various solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do something only if element exist

```
$('element').length == 0; // no element found
```

By using the `.length` property we can test whether an element exists, or whether it has been found in the page.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)